# How to fix SSL error with NodeJS HTTPS server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I'm new to Stack Overflow and this is my first question, so please bear with me. I never had to ask a question until I had a problem and couldn't find a solution. Anyways, my problem is my Node JS HTTPS server that I use to host my website has a problem where when the client requests a resource such as a video or an image, it's a 50% chance that the resource will properly load for the client. The times it doesn't load I get an SSL error in the console (for example, net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 (OK)). Sometimes it will load, sometimes it won't. I don't know if I have a misconfiguration with my server or not, but I need to get this fixed. I need the resource to load for the client 100% of the time. Any help would be great.

Here's how my server is configured.

```
const reqHandler = (req, res) => {
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => body += chunk.toString());
    req.on('end', () => {
        var path = req.url.split('?')[0];
        var query = req.url.split('?')[1] || '';
        res.statusCode = 200; // Assume a good request unless otherwise indicated
        if (path.split('/').slice(-1)[0] === '') { // If client requests folder
            if (existsSync(`./${root}${path}index.js`)) { // node-http has priority
                let type = readFileSync(`./${root}${path}index.js`, 'utf-8').split('\n')[0];
                type = type.replace('//', '').trim();
                if (type === 'node-http') {
                    try {
                        delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./${root}${path}index.js`)];
                        require(`./${root}${path}index.js`).callback(req, res, body, query);
                    } catch (e) {
                        res.write(`Node HTTP exception: ${e.message}`);
                        res.end();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            } else { // Otherwise, fallback to index.html
                path = path + 'index.html';
            }
        } else { // If the client didn't request a folder
            if (path.split('.').length === 1) { // No extension? No problem!
                // See if it's a folder
                if (existsSync(`./${root}${path}/`)) { // Redirect, if exists
                    res.statusCode = 301;
                    res.setHeader('Location', path + '/');
                    res.end();
                    return;
                } else { // If not folder, assume try to find it
                    var extensions = getType('get-extensions');
                    for (var i of extensions) {
                        if (existsSync(`./${root}${path}.${i}`)) {
                            path = `${path}.${i}`;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            var extension = path.split('.').slice(-1)[0];
            // node-http
            if (extension === 'js') {
                if (!existsSync(`./${root}${path}`)) {
                    res.statusCode = 404;
                    res.end();
                    return;
                }
                let type = readFileSync(`./${root}${path}`, 'utf-8').split('\n')[0];
                type = type.replace('//', '').trim();
                if (type === 'node-http') {
                    try {
                        delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./${root}${path}`)];
                        require(`./${root}${path}`).callback(req, res, body, query);
                    } catch (e) {
                        res.write(`Node HTTP exception: ${e.message}`);
                        res.end();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (extension === 'ws') {
                // Websocket connection
                return;
            }
            // videos
            if (extension === 'mp4') {
                var vidPath = `./${root}${path}`;
                readFile(vidPath, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                            res.statusCode = 404;
                            res.end('404 Not Found');
                        }
                        res.end();
                        return
                    } else {
                        var stats = statSync(vidPath);
                        let size = stats.size;
                        let chunkSize = 10 ** 6; // 1 megabyte (1,000,000 bytes)
                        let start = req.headers.range ? Number(req.headers.range.replace(/\D/g, "")) : 0;
                        let end = Math.min(start + chunkSize, size - 1);
                        let contentLength = end - start + 1;
                        res.setHeader('Content-Range', `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`);
                        res.statusCode = 206;
                        res.writeHead(206, {
                            'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
                            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
                            'Content-Length': contentLength,
                            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
                            'Date': new Date().toUTCString()
                        });
                        let stream = createReadStream(vidPath, {start, end});
                        stream.pipe(res);
                    }
                });
                return;
            }
        }
        readFile(`./${root}${path}`, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                    res.statusCode = 404;
                    res.end('404 Not Found');
                }
            } else {
                let type = getType(path.split('.').slice(-1)[0]);
                if (type !== null) {
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', type);
                }
                res.end(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
// Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.headers.host === 'domain.com') {
        let redirectUrl = `https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`;
        res.statusCode = 301;
        res.setHeader('Location', redirectUrl);
        res.end();
        return;
    }
    reqHandler(req, res);
}).listen(80);

// HTTPS server
const server = https.createServer({
    cert: readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem').toString(),
    key: readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem').toString(),
    ca: readFileSync('/path/to/chain.pem').toString()
}, reqHandler);
server.listen(443);
```

Comment: 1) please, show your `reqHandler` function logic. 
2) How do you serve files?

Comment: I store files in a folder called RootDir which is in the same folder as my main.js file. Here's my reqHandler function (I destructured the fs module so that's why the functions are by themselves, if you were wondering). Node-http is my custom way of serving dynamic resources similar to PHP but with Node.

Comment: Try to use `reqHandler(req, res)` on the HTTPS server.  Maybe this error is sourced from the that you serve your files over an HTTP server.

Comment: I don't serve my files using the HTTP server. The HTTP server is used only to redirect traffic to the HTTPS server (the reqHandler at the bottom is so I can access the website with localhost for debugging purposes). If you see at the bottom of https.createServer, I pass in the reqHandler function.

Comment: @AbdurrahimAhmadov Hello, I thought I'd mention you since this is still an unresolved problem I'm having. Do you know of any other ways in which I can get this fixed?